# How to compare two Django models and display the answer in the third model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have two completely identical models in structure:

```
class Model_A (models.Model)
    id_value     = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=45)
    some_value_1 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    some_value_2 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    #and etc. I have many fields

class Model_B (models.Model)
    id_value     = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=45)
    some_value_1 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    some_value_2 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    #and etc. I have many fields
```

First, I try to compare all the field values with each other.

Second, if the parameters  are not the same, and write the answer in the third table(indicating each inequality by its ID and field name) .

```
 class Third_Model(models.Model):
     auto_increment_id    = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     id_value             = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=False)
     manage_objects       = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
     field_name           = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
     value_from_A         = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
     value_from_B         = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
```

How do I perform this action using Python models? Provided that the models have a lot of fields and the models themselves are more than 40 pieces.

Here is an example of what I want to do with the sql query example.

```
INSERT INTO `third_table` (`id_value`, `manage_objects`,`field_name`,  `value_from_A`, `value_from_B`)
SELECT id_value, manage_objects, param_name, fld_param , ref_param FROM
(SELECT  id_value,  'Model_name' AS manage_objects,  param_name,  max(val1) AS fld_param, max(val2) AS ref_param 
FROM ((SELECT id_value, 'some_value_1' AS param_name, some_value_1 AS val1, Null AS val2
       FROM model_a
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT id_value, 'some_value_2' as param_name, some_value_2 AS val1, Null AS val2
       FROM model_a
      )UNION ALL
      (SELECT id_value, 'some_value_1' as param_name, Null AS val1, some_value_1 AS val2
       FROM model_b
      )  UNION ALL
      (SELECT id_value, 'some_value_2' as param_name, Null AS val1, some_value_2 AS val2
       FROM model_b
      )
       ) tcd
GROUP BY id_value, param_name
HAVING NOT max(val1) <=> max(val2)) as inconsis
WHERE CAST(fld_param AS CHAR) !='Null' AND CAST(ref_param AS CHAR) !='Null';
```

Here is what I ideally want to get:

I would like to group inconsistencies by their ID and fields name.

I have 1 table and 2 table with identical ID's.

```
Table model_a
+------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| #    | id_value   | some_value_1| some_value_2  | some_value_3            |
+------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| 1523 | Wien       | AUT         | Wien          | {"Population": 1608144} |
| 1524 | Graz       | AUT         | Steiermark    | {"Population": 240967}  |
| 1525 | Linz       | AUT         | North Austria | {"Population": 188022}  |  
+------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+

Table model_b
+------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| #    | id_value   | some_value_1| some_value_2  | some_value_3            |
+------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| 1523 | Wien       | RUS         | Wien          | {"Population": 666666}  |
| 1524 | Graz       | AUT         |               | {"Population": 240967}  |
| 1525 | Linz       | AUT         | North Austria | {"Population": 188022}  |
+------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+



Table third_model
+---+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| # | id_value   |  manage_objects  |  field_name  | value_from_a           |      value_from_b       |  auto_increment_id   |
+---+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| 1 | Wien       |      model_a     | some_value_1 | AUT                    | RUS                     |          1           |
| 2 | Wien       |      model_a     | some_value_3 |{"Population": 1608144} | {"Population": 666666}  |          2           |
| 3 | Graz       |      model_a     | some_value_2 |                        | Steiermark              |          3           |
+---+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider something along the lines of:

```py
# Get instances to be compared, for example, if you are going through all instances:
model_a_queryset = Model_A.objects.all()

for instance_a in model_a_queryset:
    instance_b = Model_B.objects.get(id=instance_a.id)
    # Since both Model_A and Model_B have the same fields, 
    # it does not matter which instance you use to get the fields and loop over them
    for field in instance_a.__class__._meta.fields:
        field_name = field.name
        # compare field values for both instances
        if getattr(instance_a, field_name) != getattr(instance_b, field_name):
            # create instance of Model_C if fields are not the same
            instance_c = Model_C(
                id_value=instance_a.id,
                value_from_A=getattr(instance_a, field_name),
                value_from_B=getattr(instance_b, field_name),
            ).save()
```

Comment: Maybe I didn’t put it that way, but I wanted a comparison of the values ​​that are directly in the fields.  @Nader Alexan

Comment: @DavidGrigoryev, I am not sure I understand. `if getattr(instance_a, field_name) != getattr(instance_b, field_name)` compares the values in the fields. Maybe give an example of instances of the models and the expected output?

Comment: @DavidGrigoryev I think I see where the miscommunication is happening here, you're using the word "value" to refer to both fields and values? -- I've added comments to my code to make it more descriptive.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments in the code - it became clear to me.
Could you tell me how to group the output by ID and by the name of the fields?
Also a problem with iteration, it only checks the first record.
Here is what I ideally want to get: (I edited the question). @Nader Alexan

Comment: @DavidGrigoryev, oh that's quite straight forward, just remove the `continue` as it was meant to look for only the first difference in two instances. Try it now and let me know if this what you meant

Comment: I did exactly as you wrote - everything goes fine, but the check goes only on the first record (in the example ID is checked only by Wien), the rest of the records are not checked. I have an assumption that the point is   id_value = instance_a.id, @Nader Alexan

Comment: @DavidGrigoryev, Are you looping over all the instance you want to examine? Can you maybe share the code you're currently running? 
I imagine that you are missing an outter loop. I have updated the answer to loop over a list

Comment: Thanks, your example really helped

Comment: @DavidGrigoryev Your welcome, it would be great if you can mark it as the correct answer then.